# Mother vertex of a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I am trying to find all mother vertex in a directed graph.

A mother vertex in a directed graph G = (V,E) is a vertex v such that all other vertices in G can be reached by a path from v.

My Approach:

Do DFS on each vertex and check if all the vertex are reached on each start node.
Time complexity : O(V*(V+E)).

I am looking for any better solutions with better complexity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the strongly connected components. If the component graph has more than one source, then there are no mother vertices. Otherwise, the mother vertices are those that belong to the single source.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by source in a component? If we take this graph,http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/SCC.png It has 3 components,but has one mother vertex.

Comment: Actually 0,1,2 are all mother vertices. A source is a vertex with no incoming edges.

Comment: Is there a way where I can find source vertices by SCC?

Comment: I'll let you figure that out.